# Isset function with age greeting PHP

Tags: php, isset

I am starting to learn PHP and and I'm stuck with this exercise...
Here is the user experience we aim for :
First, users see a form asking for their age :

```
Please type your age : __
```

When they submit the form, the page displays the right message:

```
if age is less than 12 years old, display "Hello kiddo!"
if age is between 12 and 18 years old, display "Hello Teenager !"
if age is between 18 and 115 years old, display Hello Adult !"
if age is beyond 115 years old, display "Wow! Still alive ? Are you a robot, like me ? Can I hug you ?"
```

Have both the form and the processing script in the same file. Use the GET method.

Here is a headstart.

```
// 3. "Different greetings according to age" Exercise

if (isset($_GET['age'])){
    // Form processing

}
// Form (incomplete)
?>
<form method="get" action="">
    <label for="age">...</label>
    <input type="" name="age">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Greet me now">
</form>
```

I really don't know how to use the isset in this function :-(
Can anyone give me a little push? It would be welcome! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. What do you mean you don't know how to use `isset`? Do you know how it works/have you checked the manual on it? You seem to be on the right path, just add your logic/display inside your existing condition.

Comment: @Jeto well I know roughly what it is for but I don't know if I should declare a variable first and then go through all those steps with "IF", ... I first thought with if (isset ($ _ GET ['age '])) {
     $ age = $ _GET ['age']; and then the if statements ...

Comment: @Jeto thanks I think that you helped me :) going to fill in the condition.

Comment: Once you're past the isset bit, you can use a `switch` statement for testing the age, if you want to avoid lots of ifs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the explanation of [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

> Determines if a variable is declared and is different than null.

So in your case you are just checking if `$_GET['age']` has been set. If it is you would print a message depending on the input, otherwise the `if` statement will be skipped:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_GET['age']) && ctype_digit($_GET['age'])) {
        $age = $_GET['age'];

        if($age > 0 && $age <= 12) {
            echo 'Hello kiddo!';
        } else if($age > 12 && $age < 18) {
            echo 'Hello Teenager !';
        } else if($age >= 18 && $age <= 115) {
            echo 'Hello Adult !';
        } else if($age > 115) {
            echo 'Wow! Still alive ? Are you a robot, like me ? Can I hug you ?';
        }
    }
?>

<form method="get" action="">
    <label for="age">Please type your age: </label>
    <input type="text" id="age" name="age" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Greet me now">
</form>
```

I also added a `type="text"` attribute to your input element as well as an `id` which the `<label>` uses to refer to the proper element using it's `for` attribute.

Note: the [`ctype_digit()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) method above checks if a variable has numeric characters. This is optional and can be removed, although it helps to make sure that the correct value types have been passed.

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this, its works and I can finally proceed with the ex! Have a nice WE!

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend you to check related [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) along with examples there. Just to give you that **little push**:

- **isset** (in your case) is used to check if age is presented in $_GET array. This translates to: Check if form was submitted with particular value for **age**
- Your job (if the above is true) is compare value of **$_GET['age']** with any of your rules and display what's required as a message.

```
if (isset($_GET['age']) && is_int($_GET['age'])){
    // Form processing
    // Form processing
    $providedAge = $_GET['age'];
    
    switch ($providedAge) {
        case $providedAge <= 12:
            echo 'Hello kiddo!';
            break;
        case $providedAge > 12 && $providedAge < 18:
            echo 'Hello Teenager !';
            break;
        case $providedAge >= 18 && $providedAge <= 115:
            echo 'Hello Adult !';
            break;
        case $providedAge > 115:
            echo 'Wow! Still alive ? Are you a robot, like me ? Can I hug you ?';
            break;
        default:
            echo 'Ops!';
    }
}
// Form (incomplete)
?>
<form method="get" action="">
    <label for="age">...</label>
    <input type="" name="age">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Greet me now">
</form>
```

Please if you're not familiar with **[switch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)** construction check that as well

Comment: Also this has helped me a lot with the case scenario! thx and have a nice WE! Gonna study the documentation a lot more but it is a little confusing at the beginning I think...

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach that can be quite easily extended by modifying the source `$greetings` array only - iterate through the various greetings and stop when the given age exceeds the maximum for that greeting.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='get'>
            <label for='age'>...Age: <input type='' name='age'></label>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Greet me now'>
        </form>

        <?php


            
            /* Only proceed if there is a GET variabe `age` set... otherwise do nothing */
            if( isset( $_GET['age'] ) ){
                
                /* Set the max age for each greeting as the key */
                $greetings=array(
                    0   =>  'Hello glint in your father\'s eye',                            #if below zero
                    12  =>  'Hello kiddo!',                                                 #if age is less than 12 years old
                    18  =>  'Hello Teenager!',                                              #if age is between 12 and 18 years old
                    115 =>  'Hello Adult!',                                                 #if age is between 18 and 115 years old
                    116 =>  'Wow! Still alive? Are you a robot, like me? Can I hug you?'    #if age is beyond 115 years old
                );
                
                /* filter the Querystring variable and ensure we are dealing with a numeric value only */
                $age=filter_var(
                    filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'age', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT ), 
                    FILTER_VALIDATE_INT
                );
                
                if( is_numeric( $age ) ){
                    /* loop through the greetings and stop when the given age exceeds the value for the key */
                    foreach( $greetings as $i => $greeting ){
                        if( $age <= $i )break;
                    }
                    echo $greeting;
                }
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: wow that's a whole different approach! THX man!